# How to prove that a concurrent object is linearizable?

Tags: concurrency, cpu-registers, mutual-exclusion

Is there a method to prove if an object is linearizable?
For example for the code below. How can I prove that the counter is linearizable?

here is the algorithm of the shared counter:

```
CompareAndSet R = new CompareAndSet(0);

increment() {
   Boolean ret; int r;
   repeat r = R.read(); ret = R.cas(r, r+1)
   until(ret = true)
   return
}

read() {
 return R.read();
}
```

CompareAndSet is an object that contains:

- an int v
- a method read(): returns the value of v
- a method cas(expected, update): takes 2 arguments: an `expected` value and an `update` value. If the current `v` value is equal to the expected value, then it is replaced by the update value; otherwise, the value is left unchanged. The method call returns a Boolean indicating whether the value `v` changed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you need to show that for each method that mutates the concurrent object, there is a "linearization point" where the method takes effect.

For your counter, it is trivial. If we assume that `R.cas()` is performed atomically, then your linearization point in `increment()` is when `R.cas()` succeeds in updating the value.

Comment: How can we prove that a linearization point is a linearization point?